# Unable to add parameters to api path containing "." character

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager Version 2.0.0. Within the API Publisher, I added a POST endpoint to my API using an in path parameter.

`POST /person/{id}`

Everything works fine. The path parameter `id` is added to the endpoint.

But this does not work if the path contains a `.` character somewhere. Adding `POST /cool.person/{id}` will result in an empty parameter list. Also, it is not possible to add a parameter manually to this endpoint.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I think that should work. Please enable wire logs and post logs.
http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: I enabled debug logging as described, but no extra information was written. But are you be able to reproduce the problem? I'm only using the simple standalone installation running on my local machine. Nothing special at all. It was just a quick test.

Comment: It works fine for me. You should see wire logs when you send a request. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge and due my findings on this, both `POST /person/{id}` and `POST /cool.person/{id}` are correct.
I think the issue is in your **endpoint**, your end point is not giving permission to you to add another entry **via a POST method**.
I followed your path and I couldn't reproduce your situation, but I found that need permission from endpoint to put another entry there.
I'll attach my **synaps file** and **snap shot of the response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="admin--UrlTest"
     context="/paternType/1.0"
     version="1.0"
     version-type="context">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/persons.list" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIsandboxEndpoint_0">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/persons" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIproductionEndpoint_1">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/personlist" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"/>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIproductionEndpoint_2">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--UrlTest_APIsandboxEndpoint_2">
                     <http uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                     <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS"
                               value="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.APIMgtLatencyStatsHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
         <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
         <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

[image: GET request and two POST requests]

[image: Firt POST request as <code>/persons</code>]

[image: Second POST request as <code>/persons.list</code>]

Jeewana.

Comment: As another point, in your endpoint, it may contain a service which has URL pattern like '/person/{id}'. But there may not any service which has URL pattern like '/cool.person/{id}'. **So my point is "." character is not the reason, reason may be the endpoint service**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.The main problem is actual not the endpoint, but more the fact that I cannot add parameters to it within the publisher UI. So when you are defining cool.person/{id} in the publisher, does it actually show the parameter? Or are you able to add another query parameter for example?